# Is there any chance of local PC getting infected when you analyse PCAP malware file on a cloud server through putty?

Tags: network, malware

Is there any chance of my local PC getting infected when I analyse PCAP malware file on a cloud server through putty? I want to run pcap malware to test snort in my cloud server. I want to know on doing so if it will affect my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing it remotely, it is very unlikely to affect your local system unless you either expose your local system's services via tunneling or there is a previously unknown vulnerability in the software you are using (Putty). The malware would also need to be specifically designed for such a particular attack vector, which is also rather unlikely.

Comment: I tried to download  malware pcap on ubuntu VM in microsoft azure from the putty but it is not allowing me to do so .It gives following output: 
2016-12-17-traffic-analysis-exercise.pcap.zip: Permission denied
Cannot write to ‘2016-12-17-traffic-analysis-exercise.pcap.zip’  
can you please tell me how can we download .

Comment: @bura and have you checked the permissions on the location you are saving it to, like it suggests?

Comment: @schroeder and multithr3at3d , thank you for the advice. it is working now with sudo command.